# Offset between input (sensor_msgs::PointCloud2) and its conversion to (pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>) [RViz]

Tags: rviz, sensor-msgs, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a input cloud called `cloud` of type `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr&` and want to convert it to `cloud_conv` of type `enter code here` :

```
void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud)
{
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_conv (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::fromROSMsg(*cloud, *cloud_conv);
```

Publishing `*cloud` into Rviz directly without conversion plots the correct result as a sanity check:

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 testcloud;
testcloud.header.frame_id = "base_link";
pub_test.publish(*cloud);
```

However plotting the converted cloud (and reconverted back) shows the correct cloud in RViz but with some offset in all x,y, and z directions:

```
sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 testcloud;
pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud_conv, testcloud);
testcloud.header.frame_id = "base_link";
pub_test.publish(testcloud);
}
```

So my question is, how to I make sure `testcloud` has no offset in x,y,z in regards to the input (reference) cloud `*cloud`? Is there some parameter for this that I'm missing? I have tried searching and am lost, thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326279/offset-between-input-(sensor_msgs::pointcloud2)-and-its-conversion-to-(pcl::pointcloud%3Cpcl::pointxyz%3E)-%5Brviz%5D/) by [sm0ke](https://answers.ros.org/users/43093/sm0ke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error was not taking the right reference frame, beginner mistake :)

---

Originally posted by [sm0ke](https://answers.ros.org/users/43093/sm0ke/) with karma: 16 on 2019-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0